# String Tokenizer in java for alphabets

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I have a peculiar regex kind of requirement.

I have a string like

```
Get Carter,Tigerland,Super, The,Wolf, The.
```

Here "Super, The" and "Wolf, The" are single word.

I need to tokenize it as follow

```
"Get Carter"
"Tigerland"
"Super, The"
"Wolf, The"
```

The only thing I have to note is commas in single word are followed by space, while commas between two different words do not have a space following.

Is there anything in string tokenizer like checking for ",W", where W is any alphabet?

Answer (score 2):

You want a negative lookahead, `",(?! )"`.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried like this..                                   String Genre = "Get Carter,Tigerland,Super, The,Wolf, The";
StringTokenizer Genresplit = new StringTokenizer(Genre, ",(?! )");
 while (Genresplit.hasMoreTokens()) {
  System.out.println(Genresplit.nextToken());
  } I get like this                                 Get
Carter
Tigerland
Super
The
Wolf
The -- All words separate...